# Check if button is pressed or not

Tags: ruby, string, return-value, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a Raspberry Pi with a Siri Proxy that is controlling my garage door, the garage door has only one command for open and close. To check if the garage door is opened to not I bought a magnet switch and I builded a flout point button. I already tried

```
doorstate = `gpio read 5`.chomp #gives value 1 or 0, 1 is opened, 0 is closed

print doorstate

if doorstate == "1"
 print "The garage door is already opened.\n"

elsif doorstate == "0"
 print "OK, I'll open it for you!\n"

else
 print "Error, please open it manually.\n"

end
```

Can someone please tell me how I can check fi the returned value or string from `doorstate = 'gpio read 5'` is equal to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here that the result of 'gpio read 5' contains a line ending.
Try chomping it off:

```
doorstate = `gpio read 5`.chomp
```

To verify the class of `doorstate`, insert `p doorstate.class` at line 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your single quotes (`'`) to backticks (`, the little thing with the tilde on your keyboard). That will execute the command. The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: I edited the script and pasted it in the post above but it always prints out "Error, please open it manually.". Any fix? Maby it is a Value and no string?

Comment: @DavidG.: That's not a ruby error, that's for sure. I don't know what to do about that.

Comment: But the terminal gives me the correct values, it I type "gpio read" 5 it gives me either 1 or 0, it depends on whether the button is pressed or not

Comment: I just tested it by setting the doorstate to 0 (doorstate = "0") and it printed out the right output. So it might be a value, int, number… . How can I test if?

Comment: @DavidG just insert `p doorstate` and `p doorstate.class` .